# Selenium chrome driver is slow

Tags: selenium

I am running some time dependent tests in selenium. For some reason when a insatiate a chrome driver, the load time of the browser window is varying. How can I fix this to get the load times consistent and stop the chrome browser windows from loading so slow?

Comment: Are you using grid to launch the chrome browser on a node?

Comment: No I’m not using grid, I am running the tests locally on my machine

Comment: Can you please share your chrome, chromedriver and selenium versions information.

Comment: Did you use `implicitWait`?

Comment: I am using chrome Version 75.0.3770.100. Chrome driver version is 75.0.3770.90. And I am using selenium Java jar version 3.141.59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing in common with Selenium, you need to get a snapshot of what's going on with your operating system when you launch the browser, for example using [Windows Performance Monitor](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-performance-monitor-windows-10)

Blind shot: Chrome browser is very memory intensive (you can check how much RAM it consumes using [Windows Task Manager](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-windows-10-task-manager-monitor-system-performance) and if your machine is short on RAM it starts intensively using [page file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) to store some memory pages to disk and since disk is much slower comparing to the RAM - you're getting inconsistent results.

The only way of effective speeding up Selenium tests is [Parallel Execution](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices) via [Selenium Grid](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) or by means of your underlying [unit testing framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks).

Comment: Yes, my system performance was bad when the tests were running, a lot of memory was in use due to all the browser windows I needed to open and eclipse also taking up some of the available memory. Thanks for the help